# How to call my method in cocoa, self doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Working on a program that will record some things from the webcam when a user presses physical buttons connected to the mac via phidgets. Have call methods on other places in my app simply doing [self method: input], but on one place it doesn't work. What could be wrong?

This is the method i want to run if i get inputchange in my program.

Also i do -(void)reportButton2:(NSInteger)inputVal:(NSInteger)inputInd; in my  .h file.

```
-(void)reportButton2:(NSInteger)inputVal:(NSInteger)inputInd {

//NSLog(@"phidget för port = %%d med signal %%d", ind, val);

if(inputVal == 1)
{

    NSError* error;

    NSFileManager* deleteMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString* path = @"/Users/Shared/tempFile.mov";
    [deleteMgr removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];

    [mCaptureMovieFileOutput recordToOutputFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/Shared/tempFile.mov"]];

}
else if(inputVal == 0)
{
    [mCaptureMovieFileOutput recordToOutputFileURL:nil];
}  
}
```

The code below give me result if imput from the buttons change. Here i just can't seem to call reportbutton2.

If i try to use [self reportButton2..] in gives me "Use of undeclared identifier 'self'"

```
int gotInputChange(CPhidgetInterfaceKitHandle phid, void *context, int ind, int val) {

what to do here?

return 0; 

}
```

Comment: Where is gotInputChange called from?

Comment: i have a api from the phidget that calls that when it registers an input from the device i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that gotInputChange is a C function not a Objective C method and so has no udea what self is as it does not belong to a class.

for [self reportButton2... = to work it needs to be a method in your class

Answer (score 2):

I usually put something like this at the top of callbacks like `gotInputChange`:

```
MyObject *self = (id)context;
```

Then I can use `self` throughout the function as if it were a method.

The other thing being in a function makes harder is asserting conditions. The regular assertion macros, such as `NSAssert` and `NSParameterAssert`, require both of the implicit arguments to every method (`self` is one of them) to exist. In a C function, you must use `NSCAssert`, `NSCParameterAssert`, etc. instead.

Comment: +1 for mentioning NSCAssert ... I was googling to try and find "how do I call NSAssert from a C function obj-c"

Answer (score 2):

You can also use your delegate.

```
SomeNameAppDelegate *delegate = (SomeNameAppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate yourMethodName];
```

It works like in example if your target method in AppDelegate class. But when you have an access to delegate, you can create a pointers to necessary classes and use them over delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest but not soo nice way is to make your Class a singleton and access it from the gotInputChange function.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks! Din't have any clue that it was C would never have solved it by myself. Did some googeling and this one did the trick for me.

```
[(id)context performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reportButton2:)withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ind], [NSNumber numberWithInt:val], nil] waitUntilDone:NO];
```