# Update of UITextField using 'self.' Only Working on viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have an `UITextField` on the `MainStoryboard`.
It is set and linked in `ViewController.h` :

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *finalTextField;
```

In `ViewController.m` I have `@synthesize finalTextField;` after the `@implementation ViewController`

In the `-viewDidLoad` area I can successfully update that `UITextField` by using the code:

```
self.finalTextField.text = @"99";
```

That works just fine.

But if I use that same code to update that same TextField *anywhere* else in `ViewController.m` I continue to get the error:

> "*Use of undeclared identifier 'self'* "

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to ensure that this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956287/how-to-call-my-method-in-cocoa-self-doesnt-work) isn't your problem, , when you try to use self in viewDidAppear you get that error?

Comment: Show us how and where you do it "elsewhere"

Comment: Are you sure you have an ***NS*** TextField, because I'm fairly sure AppKit isn't on iOS.

Comment: That error does not appear in viewDidAppear. New to obj-c. Understand VisualBasic. I am using that code in a method:

   void decode(NSString* textToDecode) {
...
}

Comment: My typo:  UITextField   not NSTextField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void decode(NSString* textToDecode) { ... }
```

is *not* a method, it is a "c" function and thus not a part of the class and this has no access to instance variables. Make it a method such as:

```
- (void)decodeText:(NSString *)text { ... }
```

@David Brunow's comment suggests the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Changing it to a method worked. I would not have understood the inference on the article shown by @David but I do now.